# Angularjs state binding

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have 2 components (say component A and component B), which are **far off** in the component hierarchy. I wish to toggle the visibility of the **component A** based on an event in the **component B**. I am trying to pass this state through a service that both the components share.

I tried a few approaches and none of them worked for me. I am not sure whether that is expected or if I am doing something wrong.

**ControlService**

```
@Injectable()
export class ControlService {
    public isOpenState: Boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    enable() {
        this.isOpenState = true;
    }

    disable() {
        this.isOpenState = false;
    }

    isOpen() {
        return this.isOpenState;
    }

}
```

**Approach 1**

**Component Foo**

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    private isOpen:Boolean;

    constructor(controlService: ControlService) {
        this.isOpen = controlService.isOpenState;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" *ngIf="isOpen"> </div>
```

**Approach 2**

**Component Foo**

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    private isOpen:Boolean;
    private controlService: ControlService;

    constructor(_controlService: ControlService) {
        this.controlService = _controlService;
    }

    fetchState(){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Hello Component');
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" *ngIf="controlService.isOpen()"> </div>
```

**Approach 3**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" *ngIf="controlService.isOpenState"> </div>
```

None of the above are working for me as expected, the state of the component does not reflect the state in the service. 
Which of these is the right approach, and what am I missing in them? If neither, what is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Please add the HTML that shows how you use `*ngIf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    private isOpen:Boolean;

    constructor(controlService: ControlService) {
        this.isOpen = controlService.isOpenState;
    }
}
```

only updates `this.isOpen` once. Later updates to `controlService.isOpenState` won't be updated in `FooComponent`

**Approach 2**

should work if your `*ngIf` looks like

```
*ngIf="controlService.isOpen()"
```

**Approach 3**

should work if your `*ngIf` looks like

```
*ngIf="controlService.isOpenState"
```

The preferred way is using observables instead of plain properties in services so Angular gets notified about updates instead of change detection polling for changes.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: My html looks exactly what you have suggested it to be yet, it does not update the state of the component.

Comment: I assume you provide `ControlService` more than once in your application and the component that updates the state, got a different service instance injected than `FooComponent`. Provide `ControlService` only once at the root component (`AppComponent`)